# lookup specific value from other dataframe by string match

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have below mentioned two dataframe:

DF1

```
ID     Value
AL-1   Adf "& ert
AL-2   new '? rti
AL-3   oll- drt/
AL-4   plr -rte-
```

DF2

```
Value        Type           
Adf & ert    AA
new  rti     AA
oll-drt&     AB
plr-rte      AC
```

Required Output:

```
ID     Value         Type
AL-1   Adf "& ert    AA
AL-2   new '? rti    AA
AL-3   oll- drt/     AB
AL-4   plr -rte-     AC
```

I want to match characters of DF1 in Value column with characters of DF2 Value column and derive the `Type`.

Tried to use phonics library but couldn't done yet, required some suggestions here.

Comment: It looks like you don't want an exact match. Is that correct?

Comment: @MikeH. My First preference is for exact match but if there are any special characters than match the characters for most suitable match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `adist` function to get the approximate "distance" between strings for each of your values in `df1$Value` compared to `df2$Value`. Then you can take the one with the minimum distance (so exact matches will be prioritized):

```
library(utils)
df1$Type <- df2$Type[apply(adist(df1$Value, df2$Value), 1, which.min)]

df1
#    ID      Value Type
#1 AL-1 Adf "& ert   AA
#2 AL-2 new '? rti   AA
#3 AL-3  oll- drt/   AB
#4 AL-4  plr -rte-   AC
```

Comment: @Roy1245, you get that error when you are trying to pass a `list` to `[`. Have you checked the result of the `apply`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the merge function in R

```
df1=data.frame(ID=c("AL-1","AL-2","AL-3"),Value=c("Adf & ert","new '? rti","oll- drt/"))
df2=data.frame(Value=c("Adf & ert","new '? rti","oll- drt/"),Type=c("AA","AA","AB"))

df=merge(df1,df2,by = "Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy match might work.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

library(stringr)
DF1 %>% fuzzy_left_join(DF2, by = c("Value" = "Value"), match_fun = str_detect)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cbind the two data frames in case there are many columns to be merged together:

```
   cbind(df1,df2[max.col(-adist(df1$Value,df2$Value,partial=T)),])
        ID      Value     Value Type
    1 AL-1  Adf & ert Adf & ert   AA
    2 AL-2 new '? rti  new  rti   AA
    3 AL-3  oll- drt/  oll-drt&   AB
    4 AL-4  plr -rte-   plr-rte   AC
```